# Linear regression based upon categorical variables in r

Tags: r

I have had a look over the various r resources but cannot find an obvious solution to my problem. If this is answered elsewhere a pointer in the right direction would be useful.
 With the following dataset:

```
    tmp <- c(35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36)
    experiment <- factor(tmp)
    rpm <- c(10,20,40,80,120,10,20,40,80,120)
    x <- c(678,1889,3416,8916,17917,665,1385,3377,8551,16793)
    test <- data.frame(experiment,rpm,x)
```

I would like to perform regression, for instance a linear regression using lm on rpm against x:

```
    lm(x ~ rpm)
```

Thus in this example I would have two regressions, one for experiment 35 and one for experiment 36. I could subset the data but my actual data will have upwards of 200 experiments and I am wondering if I can do this with just a few lines of code?

Comment: Is this what you want to do?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471351/regression-on-subset-of-data-set

Comment: Yes thanks, knowing what to search for is key as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
dlply(test, .(experiment), function(df) with(df, lm(x ~ rpm)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works well and in a similar manner to the comment by @Docuemada