# lmList - loss of group information

Tags: r, lm

I am using lmList to do linear models on many subsets of a data frame:

```
res <- lmList(Rds.on.fwd~Length | Wafer, data=sub, na.action=na.omit, pool=F)
```

This works fine, and I get the desired output (full output not shown):

```
         (Intercept)   Length
    2492    5816.726 1571.260
    2493    2520.311 1361.317
    2494    3058.408 1286.516
    2502    4727.328 1344.728
    2564    3790.942 1576.223
    2567    2350.296 1290.396
```

I have subsetted by "Wafer" (first column above). However, within my data frame ("sub"), the data is grouped by another factor "ERF" (there are many other factors but I am only concerned with "ERF"):

```
head(sub):

    ERF Wafer Device Row Col Width Length             Date  Von.fwd Vth.fwd  STS.fwd On.Off.fwd  Ion.fwd Ioff.fwd Rds.on.fwd
 1  474  2492 11.06E  11   6   100      5 09/10/2014 12:05 0.596747 3.05655 0.295971    7874420 0.000104 1.32e-11    9626.54
 3  474  2492 11.08E  11   8   100      5 09/10/2014 12:05 0.581131 3.08380 0.299050    7890780 0.000109 1.38e-11    9193.62
 5  474  2492 11.09E  11   9   100      5 09/10/2014 12:05 0.578171 3.06713 0.298509    8299740 0.000107 1.29e-11    9337.86
 7  474  2492 11.10E  11  10   100      5 09/10/2014 12:05 0.565504 2.95532 0.298349    8138320 0.000109 1.34e-11    9173.15
 9  474  2492 11.11E  11  11   100      5 09/10/2014 12:05 0.581289 2.97091 0.297885    8463620 0.000109 1.29e-11    9178.50
 11 474  2492 11.12E  11  12   100      5 09/10/2014 12:05 0.578003 3.05802 0.294260    9326360 0.000112 1.20e-11    8955.51
```

I do not want ERF including in my lm but I do want to keep the factor "ERF" with the lm results for colouring graphs later i.e. I want this:

```
    ERF   Wafer    (Intercept)   Length
    474   2492    5816.726     1571.260
    474   2493    2520.311     1361.317
    474   2494    3058.408     1286.516
    475   2502    4727.328     1344.728
    475   2564    3790.942     1576.223
    476   2567    2350.296     1290.396
```

I know I could do this manually later by just adding a column to the results with a vector containing the correct sequence of ERF. However, I regularly add data to the set and dont want to do this every time. Im sure there is a more elegant way?

Thanks

Edit - data added for solution:

```
res <- ddply(sub, c("ERF", "Wafer"), function(x) coefficients(lm(Rds.on.fwd~Length,x)))

head(res)

    ERF Wafer (Intercept)   Length
  1 474  2492    5816.726 1571.260
  2 474  2493    2520.311 1361.317
  3 474  2494    3058.408 1286.516
  4 474  2502    4727.328 1344.728
  5 479  2564    3790.942 1576.223
  6 479  2567    2350.296 1290.396
```

If I drop ERF:

```
res <- ddply(sub, c("Wafer"), function(x) coefficients(lm(Rds.on.fwd~Length,x)))

head(res)

    Wafer (Intercept)   Length
 1  2492    5816.726 1571.260
 2  2493    2520.311 1361.317
 3  2494    3058.408 1286.516
 4  2502    4727.328 1344.728
 5  2564    3790.942 1576.223
 6  2567    2350.296 1290.396
```

Does this made sense? Did i ask the question incorrectly?

Comment: `sub` is not really name you want to use in functions that ask for an environment (data) in the argument list. `sub` is also a base R function

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll change in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, with a bit more research i've answer my own question based on this answer:

[Regression on subset of data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471351/regression-on-subset-of-data-set?rq=1)

Must look harder next time. I used ddply instead of lmList (makes me wonder why anyone uses lmList...maybe I should ask another question?):

```
res1 <- ddply(sub, c("ERF", "Wafer"), function(x) coefficients(lm(Rds.on.fwd~Length,x)))
```

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does.  I thought you *didn't* want to distinguish by `ERF` when fitting the model (i.e. you wanted to fit to Wafer only).

Comment: You are right, I dont, but somehow it seems to output what I want. The coefs are the same regardless of if I include "ERF". Its just that if I include ERF the group information is carried forward to the output. I will post some data to make sure im correct.